# Best way to get user permission

Tags: php, sql, pdo

So I'm making a small site for fun and learning. Now I use PHP and PDO.
What I'm wondering is whats the best way to do so I can see what permission the user have. Instead of making queries on every page like on a user page to see if user have permission to edit it, and then a query in forum to see if they can delete posts etc. This seems very bad. So I wonder what is the best way? Should I put a session for everything? Right now this is how I do in my login:

```
// if we found a match
if ($row) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

groups

```
  id | title | can_edit_users | can_ban_users | can_delete_post...
  1    Member        0               0                0

  id | title | can_edit_users | can_ban_users | can_delete_post...
  2     Mod          0               0                1

  id | title | can_edit_users | can_ban_users | can_delete_post...
  3    Admin         1               1                1
```

users

```
id | group_id | username | password
```

Comment: I learned the hard way to put as little as possible in the session scope.  With modern browsers users can change those variables by opening new tabs or windows and cause wrong records to be updated.  That might not be a problem in this particular case though.

Answer (score 0):

I would load the entire permission flags for the given title of logged in user. You can also use bitmask to represent many fields in one numeric digit.

Comment: The part about the bitmask is true but not a necessary optimization.